# Custom order by in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sorting algorithms in many programming languages allow for custom object comparison. For example c++ std library implements:

```
constexpr void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

Where `comp` is a custom implementation that compares two values. The sorting algorithm calls this comparison function to determine which of the two values go first in the sorting order.
Is it possible in Snowflake to use `order by` that would call a stored procedure to do custom comparison?

Comment: This will not work. SPs cannot interact with rows in a SQL statement this way. A UDF or UDTF can interact with rows, but there's no construct in place to create a custom comparator. For some simple use cases it may be possible to use a procedural UDF or UDTF, but it would depend on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

The best we can do with SQL (AFAIK) is having a custom UDF in the `order by` - but you need to produce a key for each element, so the keys can be compared in the usual way.

For example, sorting fruits by the length of the string and then the first letter:

```sql
create or replace function custom_comp(a variant)
returns array
as 
$$
  [len(a), left(a::string, 1)]
$$;

with data as (
    select $1 x
    from (values('apple'), ('pear'), ('orange'), ('apricot'), ('mango'), ('apple'))
)
select *
from data
order by custom_comp(x::variant)
;
```

[image]